# Python Flask application host in IIS with fast cgi process

Tags: python-2.7, flask, windows-7, iis-7, fastcgi

Please guide me how python2.7 Flask framework application host in IIS with fast CGI process. I searched so many ideas on the internet but it doesn't help me till now. Anyone can give me simple process to do it and if you have video tutorial then please share the link of it. Some trial I want to specify,

1. Install IIS feature 'on' like CGI
2. Create Virtual Environment and link to physical project folder
3. Convert to Application
4. select application --> Click on Handler Mapping--> Add Script Map and input required data like *.py, python27.exe %s %s --> ok
5. Placed all .py file in 'cgi-bin' folder
6. convert into application
7. Edit in 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config'

   > 
8. Open application in browser with sample py application like print 'Hello'.  Getting output as I mentioned in sanp. 
   [image]

*** First I tried with simple application then I want to host Flask Framework.

Comment: Some times getting "<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration" Error on browser.
web.config:
<system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Python_via_FastCgi" path="*.py" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python27\python.exe|C:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>